# CherryPy : Is there a best way to split the project in multiple files?

Tags: python, cherrypy, code-organization, project-organization

I'm new to CherryPy, coming from Django. I liked the way Django split the various parts of the project into many files, and I'd like to do the same in CherryPy, instead of having one big file.

I think it would be great if I could split the project in these parts:

- application.py : The core of CherryPy, where the server starts
- urls.py : Containing all the urls, probably using RoutesDispatcher
- models.py : Via SQLAlchemy, containing all the models
- controllers.py : Pretty obvious ;)

I'm not asking for a complete code paste here, a link to an example/pastebin/gist is perfect too :)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I'll answer myself on that one :p

I found a [Google Groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/2fb617643ff9e5e7) that poses the basics on how to structure your CherryPy application.

In that post, there is a link to a [Bitbucket CherryPy application example](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/twiseless/src) that is very well structured and could be used as a base example for any CherryPy application.

Comment: Sadly, the Bitbucket link is dead but I found probably the same project on GitHub: https://github.com/Lawouach/Twiseless